# .NET: How does one provide multiple implementations of a grandchild dependency to make two different child dependency instances?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I want an application (let's say a console application) to have its main service use the same dependency twice (two different implementations of the same interface). I've read links like [this](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/december/registering-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-aspnet-core/) (section "Using a delegate to select specific interface implementation") that provide a factory function to generate the multiple implementations. I need to take this problem one level lower, however.

The dependent object is actually the same implementation except that it has its own dependent object that will differ. The object graph is something like this:

```
A (main service)
-> B (child dependency)
   -> C_1 (grandchild dependency, implementation 1)
-> B (same child dependency, second instance)
   -> C_2 (grandchild dependency, implementation 2)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use just constructor injection to wire all of this up. Here is some sample code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main( string[] args )
    {
        await Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
            .ConfigureServices( services =>
            {
                new ServicesInstaller().AddServices(services);
            })
            .RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class ServicesInstaller
{
    public void AddServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        // What do I do here to give two different implementations of C to two different
        // instances of B, so that A can use each instance of B separately?
        services.AddSingleton<IB, B>();
        services.AddSingleton<IC, C_Impl_1>();

        services.AddHostedService<A>();
    }
}

public interface IB
{
    void Do_B_Stuff();
}

public interface IC
{
    void Do_C_Stuff();
}

public class A : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IB b1;
    private readonly IB b2;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime hostLifetime;

    // b1 needs to be class B that has a dependency on C_Impl_1
    // b2 needs to be class B that has a dependency on C_Impl_2
    public A(IB b1, IB b2, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime )
    {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        hostLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        b1.Do_B_Stuff();
        b2.Do_B_Stuff();

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // Quit.
        hostLifetime.StopApplication();
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Implementations:

```cs
public class B : IB
{
    private readonly IC c;

    public B(IC c) => this.c = c;

    public void Do_B_Stuff() => c.Do_C_Stuff();
}

public class C_Impl_1 : IC
{
    public void Do_C_Stuff() => Console.WriteLine( "implementation #1");
}

public class C_Impl_2 : IC
{
    public void Do_C_Stuff() => Console.WriteLine("implementation #2");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) library contains no features for implementing *conditional binding*. This means that you have to revert to your old method, namely: registering delegates:

```
services.AddSingleton<C_Impl_1>();
services.AddSingleton<C_Impl_2>();

services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(c =>
    new A(
        b1: new B(c.GetRequiredService<C_Impl_1>()),
        b2: new B(c.GetRequiredService<C_Impl_2>()),
        hostApplicationLifetime:
            c.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>())
```

Optionally, in case you expect the constructors or either `A` or `B` to change over time, and you rather want to be able to use Auto-Wiring, you can make use of the `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` method. It enables Auto-Wiring:

```
services.AddSingleton<C_Impl_1>();
services.AddSingleton<C_Impl_2>();

services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(c =>
  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<A>(c,
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<B>(c, c.GetRequiredService<C_Impl_1>()),
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<B>(c, c.GetRequiredService<C_Impl_2>())
  )
);
```

**UPDATE:**

> Do you know of other DI frameworks that do have support for solving this kind of issue?

As I noted in the comments, your problem is actually tricky for DI Containers, because `B` is not really `Singleton` (as there are two instances). This will confuse containers, even the ones that can do conditional registrations based on grand parents. The only Container I am experienced enough to talk about is Simple Injector (which I maintain). Here's an example of how to implement this with Simple Injector:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<IHostedService, A>();

container.RegisterConditional<IB, B<C_Impl_1>>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "b1");
container.RegisterConditional<IC, C_Impl_1>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(B<C_Impl_1>));

container.RegisterConditional<IB, B<C_Impl_2>>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "b2");
container.RegisterConditional<IC, C_Impl_2>(
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(B<C_Impl_2>));
```

The registrations above depend on a new type, namely `B<T>`, which derives from `B` and can be placed inside your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/):

```cs
class B<T> : B where T : IC
{
    public B(IC c) : base(c) { }
}
```

This type can be used to differentiate between the two versions of `B` that exist (a `B` with an `C_Impl_1` and a second be depending on `C_Impl_2`). This new generic type allows to remove the confusion.

You'll end up with the following object graph:

```
new A(
    b1: new B<C_Impl_1>(new C_Impl_1()),
    b2: new B<C_Impl_2>(new C_Impl_2()),
    hostApplicationLifetime: new HostApplicationLifetime>());
```

> **NOTE:** There are more compact ways to define this object graph in Simple Injector, but this specific way of wiring allows Simple Injector to Auto-Wire all other dependencies in `A`, `B`, `C_Impl_1`, and `C_Impl_2`, while allowing the container to analyze, verify, and diagnose your object graphs.

This method has the following downsides:

- Requires the definition of a new `B<T>`, which solely consists to simplify registration in your container (tip: this trick might work with other DI Containers as well).
- The registration depends on the exact naming of `A`'s constructor arguments (but at least Simple Injector's verification feature will pick up mismatches immediately).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I was afraid that there wouldn't be an elegant way to do this, and my fears appear to be correct.  But, your answer (especially the second part) at least points in a direction where the non-DI-messiness can be contained to just the ServicesInstaller portion and not pollute the actual class' constructors.

Comment: Tip: Chapter 15 of [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl) shows more of these kinds of tricks concerning the building of more complex object graphs in MS.DI. But big spoiler: maintainability of your Composition Root starts to break down rapidly when building more-complex applications with MS.DI.

Comment: Do you know of other DI frameworks that do have support for solving this kind of issue?

Comment: Your problem is actually tricky for DI Containers, because `B` is not really Singleton (as there are two instances). This will confuse containers, even the ones that can do conditional registrations based on grand parents. The only Container I am experienced enough to talk about is Simple Injector (which I maintain), but you will likely to achieve similar results with Autofac and Ninject.

Comment: BTW, that book you referenced is similar to "DI in .NET" by one of the same authors (Mark Seemann) and publisher from 2012, which is one of my all-time favorites.  Really well written and opened a lot of doors for me.  Can't recommend it enough.

Comment: The book I referenced is the second edition of "DI in .NET". I coauthored that edition.

Comment: I updated my answer demonstrating Simple Injector.